# Create Folder and save file through fileopenDialog

Tags: vb.net

i am using FileOpenDialog control to save file in C: drive,
Now i want to create New Folder and save the file in that folder with FileOpenDialog.
and also from other forms i have to store different file in that same foldr.
Please any one suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

i think this link may help you
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bc2c92a-b22f-484c-9a15-0aebf639422d/folder-browser-dialog-in-vbnet-2010
by the way you should use SavefFileDialog or FolderBrowserDialog

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the SaveFileDialog to save the file. Not the file open dialog. The SaveFileDialog control will automatically let the user also create a folder -- just open the dialog in run-time mode and right click inside and see.. New > New Folder. Once the user navigates into this newly created folder and specifies the file name, all you need to do is to save the file.

Alternately, if you want to use a fixed subfolder, don't prompt the user to create the folder for you. Instead after the dialog is dismissed, do this --

```
    string savePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(savePath);

    savePath = string.Format(
                  "{0}\\MySubFolder\\{1}", 
                      directory, 
                        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(savePath)
                );
```

Save the file to the path in "savePath".

(PS: Sorry my above snippet is in C#, but you should be able to easily convert it to VB.NET).